# Trying to get 9 consecutive HTML tags

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running the following code and getting all nulls, which can't be correct.

```
for link in page_source:
    wd.get(link)
    #print(link)
    html_page = wd.page_source 
    soup = bs(html_page, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('_id\=')}):
    link_text = a['href']

    if '/admin/airflow/tree?dag_id=' in link_text and '&num_runs=' not in link_text:

        ID = re.match('(.*)_id=(\w+)', link_text).group(2)

        cir1 = soup.find_all('circle')[0].text
        cir2 = soup.find_all('circle')[1].text
        cir3 = soup.find_all('circle')[2].text
        cir4 = soup.find_all('circle')[3].text
        cir5 = soup.find_all('circle')[4].text
        cir6 = soup.find_all('circle')[5].text
        cir7 = soup.find_all('circle')[6].text
        cir8 = soup.find_all('circle')[7].text
        cir9 = soup.find_all('circle')[8].text

print(id+'|'+cir1+'|'+cir2+'|'+cir3+'|'+cir4+'|'+cir5+'|'+cir6+'|'+cir7+'|'+cir8+'|'+cir9)
```

Result:

```
barra_cae5_daily_smgm|||||||||
```

Here's in the HTML behind the page I'm working with.

[image]

There are up to 9 circle tags for each ID in `'link_text'`in each row.  Then I'm moving to the next row, getting the next ID, and all circle tags, and so on and so forth.  How can I grab these 'circle' tags?  Thanks.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code.

Comment: Since I don't actually got the real page it's hard to provide good help or actually verify any result. A couple of things to look out for is if the page is client-side rendered (can not see if so is the case since I can't see the actual page), this looks like embedded svg which might behave differently as well.

If you are working with a SPA/client side rendered page you can use for instance Requests-HTML to render and then parse pages.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the parsing; I'm getting the ID just fine.  I just can't tell if I'm looking for the right tags for the circle.  
When I try this:
cir1 = soup.find_all('transform')[0].text
I get:
IndexError: list index out of range
When i try this:
cir1 = soup.find_all('circle')[0].text
Nothing is returned, but I really think I should get a '3' because that's the text for the fist circle tag.

Comment: Oh, I got it.  It's the 'text' tag not the 'circle' tag.
cir1 = soup.find_all('text')[0].text
cir2 = soup.find_all('text')[1].text
cir3 = soup.find_all('text')[2].text